# Shell Script On Git Merge Commit

Tags: git, shell, merge, git-merge

I'm currently trying to automate a build process we use, using a shell script.

I've currently got the shell script to work for a commit that isn't a merge commit, using the script below. $1 and $2 are where the files are located and where they are being copied too. $3 is the commit hash.

```
 cd $1
 echo "Copying to $2" 
 for i in $(git show -c --pretty="format:" --name-only $3) 
     do 
        # First create the target directory, if it doesn't exist. 
        mkdir -p "$2/$(dirname $i)" 
        # Then copy over the file. 
        cp "$i" "$2/$i" 
    done 
echo "Done";
```

Is there anyway I can get this to work on a merge commit, as we only ever release the files that changed on the merge.

Comment: so with this script you seperate out files that were changed in the commit hash provided in third argument. But what if you have made more than one commit?

Comment: The script is going to be used as a custom action in source tree. The idea is we click on the merge commit in source tree, run the script and it will create our release. There should only ever be 1 commit, as it can only ever be run when highlighting 1 commit.